# tortoiseSVN repository, access from portable device

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, portable-applications, rapidsvn

I have a programming project with >20 files where I'm currently using TortoiseSVN as a versioning software. The repository is on a local harddrive and I'm the only one accessing the files.

However, I work on the code on multiple PCs (all Windows between 7 and 10), but I don't want to upload the files somewhere or make my home-pc a server. So I was considering using the portable version of RapidSVN instead on a USB device.

Now I would like to keep the "history", so I have access to all the commits.

I've heard RapidSVN is using Subversion 1.5 libraries, so I would need to downgrade to Tortoise 1.5 (I have 1.9.3 at the moment) to let them both use the same repository...

Is it possible to migrate from tortoiseSVN to RapidSVN including past revisions? Or might there be a better way?

Comment: You want to move your repo from local drive to flash?

Comment: @Y.N well, in principle yes... I just didn't know that a repository created with Tortoise can also be used by other, portable SVN software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried some things out moved to smartSVN.
It's still the testing period of the pro-version, but the foundation version also seems to offer what I need.

Apparently both recent versions, smartSVN and Tortoise can open the same Repository. smartSVN also comes with a better graphical user interface in my opinion, though it's a little hard to learn for a beginner that you have working-copies, working copy files etc.

So, I now I can just copy the repository on my USB drive and start SmartSVN on every PC to hang in a working Copy.

It also doesn't seem to support relative Paths to repositories, but calling the relocate "dialog" is pretty easy (e.g. to change the drive letter).

---

However, when I wanted to get rid of some early mistakes in revisions (like submitting a bunch of binary files within the first 10 revisions -> bloating repository up to 300MB) I still need the command-line tools from TortoiseSVN:

- `svnadmin dump -r11:100 repositoryPath > dumpfile`
- `svndumpfilter exclude -targets file.txt < dumpfile > filteredDump`
- delete repository
- create repository at repositoryPath
- `svnadmin load repositoryPath < filteredDump`
- another checkout is required

=> Repository got shrunken from 100 (300MB) to 90 (30MB) revisions

Answer (score 0):

If you have (can have) SVN-client on every workplace, it will be better to have "portable repository", than portable extremely outdated client

Comment: That's right, but I don't have a SVN client on each workplace unless I bring in a portable one... so far smartSVN seems to work fine...